# JSDoc don't parse elements prefixed with a comma

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying JSDoc and Docco with the following `test.js` file:

```
/**
 * @fileOverview Various tool functions.
 * @author <a href="mailto:jd@example.com">John Doe</a>
 * @version 3.1.2
 */

/** @namespace util */
var util = {

  // ## Multiply ##
  // with this function you can make amazing multiplications!

  /**
   * Multiplies two numbers
   * @param {int} a - a number
   * @param {int} b - another number
   * @returns {int}
   * @example
   * var m = util.multiply(2, 3); // 6
   */

  multiply: function (a, b){
    return a * b;
  }

  // ## Divide ##
  // with this function you can divide two numbers

  /**
   * Divides two numbers.
   * @param {int} a - a number
   * @param {int} b - another number
   * @returns {int} a/b
   */

, divide: function (a, b) {
    // note that if the numbers are not divisible, the result will be a float.
    return a / b;
  }
};
```

Docco outputs the doc correctly (both functions appears), but JSDoc only output one, as can be seen in the following screen captures:

Docco:

[image: Docco printscreen]

---

JSDoc:

[image: JSDoc printscreen]

Any ideas of why this happens?

Comment: Which version of jsdoc? The entire underlying mechanism on how it 'reads' the JavaScript has changed. With 3.x this should work as expected. If not, please file a bug report on Github.

Comment: Last version installed via `npm`, 3.3.2 as it is. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: @user2864740 seems it is a bug open since 2013: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the [comma first style](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/357981). There's a bug opened since 2013 with this: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/446

If I remove the comma from the beggining of the line with the `divide` function and add it after the closing brace of the `multiply` function, JSDoc generates the doc correctly:

[image: JSDoc printscreen]

**Edit:** adding GitHub issue link.

Answer (score 1):

I created a JSDoc plugin to support comma first style:
https://github.com/Booster2ooo/jsdoc-comma-first

I hope it helps.